# Doom Emacs does not display wordcount

Tags: org-mode, mode-line, words

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9.

If I make a selection, I can see the word-count. This is as expected because `doom-modeline-enable-word-count` is set to t.

However, I was expecting to see a word-count as I edit on org file because `doom-modeline-continuous-word-count-modes` is set to `markdown-mode, gfm-mode, org-mode`.

But I do not see the word-count. How do I get this working?

Comment: "`doom-modeline-continuous-word-count-modes` is set to `markdown-mode, gfm-mode, org-mode`" looks very dodgy.  If there are actually commas, then that's not the list you want it to be.  If you are just manually reformatting it for the question, then you shouldn't do that -- use lisp syntax for lisp values, otherwise you will cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a region or the whole document
(`ggvG$` if you use Evil), then use `M-=`. Emacs will display the number of lines, words, and characters.

Comment: I believe OP is asking about a word count in the modeline.

Answer (score 0):

I made it works as expected by using:

```lisp
(use-package! doom-modeline
  :custom
  (doom-modeline-enable-word-count t)
  (doom-modeline-continuous-word-count-modes '(markdown-mode gfm-mode org-mode text-mode)))
```